# About the android robotium release

Tags: android, testing, robotium

I have already finish most of the code of the robotium testing which is running on the android studio. I am just wondering which is the most effective way to make a release? To make a jar(how to do that)? Or make a interface? Because the QA team do not want to code so I have to make a platform which well organize without any code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You always may launch your tests from the command line with adb

```
adb shell am instrument -w yourproject.com/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner
```

However I would recommend you take a look on the [Spoon](http://square.github.io/spoon/) project that may help with the test instrumentation and distribution.